# Clear list data from code

Tags: list, client-object-model

I need to clear the data contained in a list programmatically.

I know I can iterate through every single item to delete it, but that takes forever.

Any suggestion?

(I'm with the **client object model** by the way)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest method is to delete list and then recreate it from scratch trough UI.
However in many scenarios this is not possible.

If you cannot use server object model to do deletion next best thing is to use [Lists.UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) webservice and preform batch deletion.

Take a look at this SO question and accepted answer:

[How to Delete all the Items from SharePoint List without iteration using SharePoint Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474886/how-to-delete-all-the-items-from-sharepoint-list-without-iteration-using-sharepo)

Answer (score 1):

As I know it allways was a problem to clear SharePoint list. I did it that way - I created a list template from my target list and then I was able to delete list and quickly recreate it again. As I remember it was a quite acceptable solution. But I did it from server side object model.

Comment: Recreating the list is a fairly expensive operation (since you get db hits for deleting the list, recreating it, and adding the items again). Also the list will have a new GUID which might mess some things up (for example if you have some web parts using GUIDs, third party apps, workflows, etc.). Best to use the UpdateListItems batch method above.